# Drop down option not working in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, menu, dropbox

I'm trying to build drop down options on mouse over and on click. The only problem I have with it, is when I put the mouse over an on child element, the menu gets hidden quickly.

jQuery code:

```
var navPos = $("#topNav").position().top; // ignore this line
// menu drop options
$('.repeat, .recitor, .volume, .bandwidthOption').bind('dropOption', function(e, force) {
    var force = force || 'toggle';

    if ($(this).hasClass('repeat'))
        var optionName = 'repeat';
    else if ($(this).hasClass('recitor'))
        var optionName = 'recitor';
    else if ($(this).hasClass('volume'))
        var optionName = 'volume';
    else if ($(this).hasClass('bandwidthOption'))
        var optionName = 'bandwidthOption';
    else
        return;

    var optionSubName = $(this).find('ul').attr('class');
    var position = $(this).position();
    position.top = navPos;
    var isActive = $(this).hasClass('active');

    if ((isActive && force != 'show') || (force && force == 'hide'))
    {
        $(this).removeClass('active');
        $('.'+optionSubName).hide();
        if (optionName == 'recitor') /* ie fix - z-index issue */
            $('.logoBox').show();
    }
    else
    {
        $(this).addClass('active');
        $('.'+optionSubName).show();
        $('.'+optionSubName).css('left',position.left+'px');
        if (optionName == 'recitor') /* ie fix - z-index issue */
            $('.logoBox').hide();
    }
});
$('.repeat, .recitor').click(function() {
    $(this).trigger('dropOption');
    return false;
});
$('.volume, .bandwidthOption').hover(function() {
    $(this).trigger('dropOption', 'show');
},function() {
    $(this).trigger('dropOption', 'hide');
});
```

Menu demo: http://jsbin.com/ozokir/2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last bit is hiding the options:

```
$('.volume, .bandwidthOption').hover(function() {
    $(this).trigger('dropOption', 'show');
},function() {
    $(this).trigger('dropOption', 'hide');
});
```

Hover is only over the link option. To solve this you could use:

```
$('.volume, .bandwidthOption').mouseover(function() {
        $(this).trigger('dropOption', 'show');
    });
```

or click as you have in the previous line. Then you can hide with:

```
$('.dropOption').mouseout(function() {
            $(this).trigger('dropOption', 'hide');
        });
```

Comment: ok i replaced the hover to mouseover and mouseout.. but didnt work, shows the same.. here is demo http://jsbin.com/ozokir/3

Comment: I think you have misunderstood me. mouseover/mouseout does pretty much the same thing as hover. Just use mouseover for showing, and then use the mouseout event on the options as a way  of hiding the options.

Comment: oh ok. but that wont be proper.. cause i just tried it and if you dont leave the mouse over from kbs, it will not hide. try it. http://jsbin.com/ozokir/5/edit#preview

Comment: Alright, so, the issue is that the link box doesn't extend all the way down to absolutely positioned ul. So, you need to make this a bit bigger, which means use inline-block. I fixed the code in the link you gave me above to do just this. It's only a css fix, so your original hover should work as well.

Comment: ic, you edited values for links a, which making problem, because my links has images on it spirtes.. is there anyway you can try it on li, rather then link. im trying, but its not working..